# Using a key that takes into account rollover or wrap of the key value in std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std, stdmap

Is it possible to have a key for a `std::map` that takes into account rollover or wrap of the key? and if so how would you implement the < operator to do that?

Suppose the key is based on a counter that has a max value, N, is it possible to have a < operator that takes into account when the key value rolls over so that the items are ordered in the map as follows:

```
 N-2
 N-1
 N
 1
 2
 3
 ...
```

In addition, is it possible to do this if key values can be skipped? For example, N is skipped so that the map has these values:

```
 N-2
 N-1
 1
 2
 3
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Utilising the `<` for `std::tuple` and `bool`, you can do something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct WrappedLess
{
    T wrap_point;
    bool operator()(const T & lhs, const T & rhs) const
    {
        return std::make_tuple(lhs < wrap_point, std::ref(lhs)) < std::make_tuple(rhs < wrap_point, std::ref(rhs));
    }
};

constexpr int N = 100;

int main() 
{
    std::map<int, std::string, WrappedLess<int>> wrapped_values({N-2}); // initally empty

    std::map<int, std::string, WrappedLess<int>> more_wrapped_values({
        {N-10, "last"}, 
        {N-2, "first"}, 
        {N-1, "second"}, 
        {1, "third"}, 
        {5, "fourth"}, 
    }, {N-2}); // initialised with some values

    for (auto & pair : more_wrapped_values)
        std::cout << pair.first << pair.second << std::endl;
}
```

[See it live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae1c711ebffea28f)

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to a key which is a class with <int,int> pair?
When I tried that it picks up the < operator on that class and does not consider the wrap point.

Comment: So I have been doing some testing using your method. Essentially, this is implementing a custom compare for the map instead of the default less. I implemented your proposed compare and it does not actually work.
Using MAX of 25, when inserts into the map are done the result near the rollover are as follows for the elements with keys of 21, 22, 23,24,25,1,2
   25
   1
   2
   21
   22
   23
   24
Changing the "wrap point" to be MAX + 1 corrects the placement of key 25 but does not work correctly for key 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how this could be implemented. The idea is to introduce a custom `Key` template that can be parametrized with the desired maximal value at compile time. Comparison and basic arithmetic operations are provided via the [boost operator library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/utility/operators.htm), such that `Key` instances with an identical max. value can be compared and added.

```
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

template <int max>
struct Key : private boost::totally_ordered<Key<max>, boost::addable<Key<max>>> {
   int value;

   Key(int init = 0) : value(init) { maybeRollOver(); }

   Key& operator+=(const Key& rhs) { value += rhs.value; maybeRollOver(); return *this; }
   const Key& operator+() const { return *this; }

   void maybeRollOver() { if (value > max) value = value % max - 1; }
};
```

This template needs two operator overloads to generate all comparison operators (see the [boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)):

```
template <int max>
bool operator==(const Key<max>& lhs, const Key<max>& rhs)
{
   return lhs.value == rhs.value;
}

template <int max>
bool operator<(const Key<max>& lhs, const Key<max>& rhs)
{
   return lhs.value < rhs.value;
}
```

And here is how to use it.

```
std::map<Key<5>, std::string> testMap;

testMap[0] = "Hello";
testMap[1] = "world";
testMap[6] = "Bye"; // "rolled over to 0, "Hello" is replaced by "Bye";

for (const auto& [key, value] : testMap)
   std::cout << key.value << ": " << value << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately we are not using boost :-(

Comment: @Louise The boost base classes do nothing but insert boilerplate code, i.e. `operator+` and `operator !=` for two `Key` instances, based on the existing code. You can easily drop the base classes and implement yourself what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I was able to get to work.

The key is actually `<unsigned int, unsigned int>` with the ordering relative to rollover only needing to take into account the first value of the key.
Also, the ID is 1 based so values will be `1, 2, ..., N, 1, 2, ...`
Finally, note that the MAX ID is large enough so that we don't ever have multiples of the same keys attempting to exist in the map at the same time. That is, by the time we get to id N, the initial 1, 2, 3... keys are long gone.

```
class Mykey(
public:
   unsigned int Id1;
   unsigned int Id2;

MyKey(unsigned int k1, unsigned in k2)
: Id1(k1), Id2(k2) {}

bool operator<(const MyKey &rhs) const
{
    if (Id1 == rhs.Id1)
        return Id2 < rhs.Id2;
    else if ( (rhs.Id1 > Id1) && (rhs.Id1 - Id1 > MAX_ID/2) )
        return false;
    else if ( (Id1 > rhs.Id1) && (Id1 - rhs.Id1 > MAX_ID/2) )
        return true;
    else
        return Id1 < rhs.Id1;
}
```

Let's say MAX_ID is 25, the first else if considers the case where rhs.Id1 is 25 and Id1 is 1. The second else considers the opposite case with Id1=25 and rhs.Id1=1. The MAX_ID/2 is checking that the two values are "far apart" indicating wrap on the ID.

Comment: Your desired behaviour is not expressible with `std::map`. The comparison is required to provide an ordering such that `a < b` and `b < c` implies `a < c`. In this case if you can have `MyKey a = { MAX_ID - 4, 0 }, b = { MAX_ID/2 - 2, 0 }, c = { 0, 0 }` we have `a < b`, `b < c` and `c < a`.

Comment: Using such a comparison with `std::map` has undefined behaviour. It's certainly plausible to end up in a state where *looking for* a particular key crashes your program or corrupts unrelated data

Comment: Hmmm ... good point! So this is not a general solution.
But, in the particular set of code, i would not have the case with a, b, c as you indicated. The map will never have more than 10-20 entries at a time. MAX_ID is 255. So having entries as far apart as `a = { MAX_ID - 4, 0 }, b = { MAX_ID/2 - 2, 0 }` is not a plausible case.